Chanukah vs. Purim and seeing vs. hearing
There are two Rabbinic holidays based around publicizing a miracle: Chanukah and Purim. On Chanukah this is accomplished through visual means, i.e. lighting candles. On Purim this is accomplished through auditory means, i.e. reading and listening to Megillas Esther.
Can anyone help me find sources that address this difference and perhaps compare and contrast Chanukah and Purim?

I saw a similar question about Chanukah being public and Purim inside synagogues, but I think my question is different enough to stand on its own.

It does seem consistent with the common theme (at least in chassidus) of Chanukah representing the aspect of G-dliness which transcends nature and Purim displaying how He works within nature. Chanukah is a time of spiritual revelation, symbolized by light and sight. Purim commemorates a more physical salvation and is celebrated accordingly, with an emphasis on the material realm where G-dliness is more obscured (אינו דומה שמיעה לראיה) yet still ever-present.

https://www.sefaria.org/Kedushat_Levi%2C_Genesis%2C_Homilies_for_Chanukah.2?lang=bi&with=all
